# Canvas tab trouble display image

Tags: jquery, image, canvas

I am new with jquery , i have a small project about display image with canvas. All will good , but i have a trouble when try display all image , i try to use .each(function) or loop  but not work

This is my trouble , any one can help ?. Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/NcKfr/6/

```
<textarea id="textid">blah  blah blah</textarea>



<canvas id="ca1" width="640" height="480"></canvas>

<script>
 $(document.body).find('*').each(function() {
    var tmp = $("textarea").children().remove();
    var text = $("textarea").text();
    text = text.replace(/<li>/g, "").replace(/<\/li>/g, "").replace(/<br \/>/g, "").replace(/\/>/g, "").replace(/<img/g, "").replace(/ /g, "");
    $("textarea").text(text);
    $("textarea").append(tmp);
    });
 </script>


Script code :

$(function(e) {


 var data = $("#textid").val();
  rows = data.split('src="');
  partNum = [];
  var i;
  var len = rows.length;
 var can = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
 var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

    $(document).ready(function() {

  for (i = 1; i < len; i++) {
 partNum[i] = rows[i].substr(0,rows[i].indexOf('"'));
 $.getImageData({
            url: partNum[i],
            success: function(image) {

                // Set the canvas width and heigh to the same as the image
                $(can).attr('width', image.width);
                $(can).attr('height', image.height);
                $(can).css({
                    'background-color': 'none',
                    'border-color': '#fff'
                });

                // Draw the image on to the canvas
                ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);

            },
            error: function(xhr, text_status) {
                // Handle your error here
            }
        });

  }


    });


});


            success: function(image) {
```

> ```
>  script = document.createElement('canvas');
> var can = document.body.appendChild(script);
> ```

If i change code in two line , i can show all image but i can control it load form 1 to 13. Any body can help me fix it ... thanks

Comment: The images get painted over each other because they are large.

Comment: Oh , now i can understand because don't control it to load form 1 to 13. I need to display it . Can i sort it ?

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative version.

http://jsfiddle.net/linkabi9/jy54Q/

HTML:

```
<textarea id="textid"> blah blah blah </textarea>
<a id="prev" href="#previous">Previous</a>
<a id="next" href="#next">Next</a>

<canvas id="ca1" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(function() {
    var $textarea = $("#textid"),
        $canvas = $("#ca1");
    var ctx = $canvas[0].getContext("2d");
    var textareahtml = $textarea.val();
    var imgsrcarray = [];
    $(textareahtml).find("img").each(function(i, o) {
        imgsrcarray.push(this.src);
    });
    var counter = 0;
    $("#prev").click(function() {
        if (counter != 0) {
            loadImg(--counter);
        } else {
            alert("Beginning");
        }
        return false;
    });
    $("#next").click(function() {
        if (counter != imgsrcarray.length - 1) {
            loadImg(++counter);
        } else {
            alert("End");
        }
        return false;
    });
    var loadImg = function(i) {
        $.getImageData({
            url: imgsrcarray[i],
            success: function(img) {
                $canvas.attr("width", img.width).attr("height", img.height);
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
            },
            error: function(xhr, text_status) {}
        });
    };
    loadImg(counter);
    return;
});
```

I took out the nested `ready` method. It's not necessary. I switched out how you parse the textarea for image urls. I added some links because your method seemed to be built to dump every image onto one canvas. That wouldn't be very useful. I moved the `getImageData` call into a method so it's reusable.

Comment: Thanks for your help about parse the text area for image urls , can i ask : Dont have solution to view all image one time ? Thanks you

Comment: You can easily call the `loadImg` method multiple times, to load all images at once, but they will be layered on top of each other. You won't ever see all the images without giving each a unique position.